# Block windows shutdown

Tags: java, windows, c++builder, shutdown

I need execute some code before Windows shutdown process each time. So, I want block Windows shutdown process for some time. How can i do it from Java or C++ Builder ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know but you are not going to endear yourself to your users in the process

Comment: Do you *need* to? Or is there a better way to have your program do things regularly, such as task scheduler or Windows Services? What are you trying to do? Can you expand upon your problem?

Comment: It's will be some logging system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [logoff or shutdown script](http://techsupt.winbatch.com/ts/T000001048F90.html) to launch an exe? This can be set by Group Policy.

Of course, I hope you have a good reason (like my corporate build) to do this. As mentioned in comments, what are you tring to do please?

Answer (score 0):

See response on WM_POWERBROADCAST message. Also take into account that your ability to prevent shut down can depends on OS (it seems on Vista and later there are additional capabilities).